# Normalized Variation of Information (NVI) visualization of distances to several references

Tags: data-visualization, matlab, python, metric

I am using NVI (Normalized Variation of Information) to measure the quality of clustering obtained ( a family of them) compared to the Ground Truth and also to the result obtained with another method.

Since NVI is a metric, it satisfies the triangular inequality and hence I thought it would be nice to plot the result graphically.

For that, I need a tool that given the distances among points can plot them in such a way that all the distances are respected among the different reference points. The graph should be 2D.

Do you know of any tool that can do like that? i.e. receiving a matrix of distances
The matrix will not be complete, that is, the distance between all the partitions is not calculated. All the distances to the 3 references (2 GT and the additional method) and the distances among the 3 references are calculated.

If not a tool, using Matlab or Python and doing some programming is also fine for me.
I have around 200 points to plot.

EDIT:
I have found this answer in SO: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513455/drawing-a-graph-or-a-network-from-a-distance-matrix
but it doesn't work properly, even for 7 nodes (that can be visually verified the correctness")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is [Multidimensional Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling). It takes a distance matrix and processes coordinates such that the distances between the points approximately respect the values in the matrix. There are implementations in many languages, such as R (see [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/mds.html)).

However, you might need (much) more than 2 dimensions if you want to obtain coordinates exactly resulting in the same distances.

Comment: I found the same solution from Matlab webpage. As you suggest, the results are not very satisfactory as to represent in a 2D or 3D space. In any case, since you provided the solution, I award you the Correct Answer.